# Prove the parity of compositions of permutation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I want to prove the following claims:

- the composition of two even permutations is even
- the composition of two odd permutations is even
- the composition of an odd and an even permutation is odd

To prove this we can prove $sign(\alpha\beta)=sign(\alpha)sign(\beta)$. Are there any other  way to prove the claims? or how to prove the sign claim?

Answer (score 1):

Define $\text{sgn}:\mathcal S_\Omega\to\{\pm 1\}$ by
$\text{sgn}:\sigma\mapsto\prod_{X\in[\sigma]}(-1)^{|X|-1}$ where $\mathcal S_\Omega$ denotes the symmetric group on $\Omega$ and $$[\sigma]:=\{\text{orb}_\sigma(x):x\in\Omega\}$$ is the family of all $\sigma$ orbits.

Because  $\mathcal S_\Omega$ is generated by its transposition elements it suffices to show $\frac{\text{sgn}(\sigma\circ\alpha)}{\text{sgn}(\sigma)}=\text{sgn}(\alpha)=-1$ when $\alpha$ is a transposition ; $\text{sgn}$ would be a group epimorphism and the permutations composed of evenly many transpositions, i.e. the even permutations, would together form $\ker(\text{sgn})$ with $$|\mathcal S_\Omega:\ker(\text{sgn})|=|\frac{\mathcal S_\Omega}{\ker(\text{sgn})}|=|\{\pm 1\}|=2$$ and we'd be done.
Let $[\sigma]_\alpha:=\{\text{orb}_\sigma(x),\text{orb}_\sigma(y)\}$ and note

$$|[\sigma]_\alpha|=2\implies [\sigma\circ\alpha]=([\sigma]\setminus[\sigma]_\alpha)\cup\{\text{orb}_\sigma(x)\cup\text{orb}_\sigma(y)\}$$
$$|[\sigma]_\alpha|=1\implies[\sigma\circ\alpha]=([\sigma]\setminus[\sigma]_\alpha)\cup\{\text{orb}_{\sigma\circ\alpha}(x),\text{orb}_\sigma(x)\setminus\text{orb}_{\sigma\circ\alpha}(x)\}$$
$$\therefore\;\;\;\frac{\text{sgn}(\sigma\circ\alpha)}{\text{sgn}(\sigma)}=\Bigg\{\begin{matrix}\frac{(-1)^{|\text{orb}_\sigma(x)|+|\text{orb}_\sigma(y)|-1}}{(-1)^{|\text{orb}_\sigma(x)|-1}\cdot(-1)^{|\text{orb}_\sigma(y)|-1}}\;\text{if}\;|[\sigma]_\alpha|=2\\\frac{(-1)^{|\text{orb}_\sigma(x)|-2}}{(-1)^{|\text{orb}_\sigma(x)|-1}}\;\text{if}\;|[\sigma]_\alpha|=1\\\end{matrix}=-1$$